# NPM install crashes

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

My newest npm constantly crashes, when I trying to install some npm package (npm install). I have to repeat this process for example for 5 times before I install all dependencies and even then, It sometimes miss some nested dependencies. So I have to go through the tree and run npm install again.

I tried to use this but with no luck. I'am not behind a proxy. Where should be problem? Installing is taking so long, and my internet connection is not slow.

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/


c:\work\projects\java\project\frontend-src\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator>npm install
npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/event-stream/-/event-stream-3.1.7.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/rcloader/-/rcloader-0.1.2.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/debug/-/debug-2.1.0.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/rcloader/-/rcloader-0.1.2.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/debug/-/debug-2.1.0.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/pause-stream/-/pause-stream-0.0.11.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/pause-stream/-/pause-stream-0.0.11.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/from/-/from-0.1.3.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/rcloader/-/rcloader-0.1.2.tgz
npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Apps\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Apps\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd c:\work\projects\java\project\frontend-src\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.32
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: Do you have some kinds of problems with your connection like package lose or something?

Comment: No, I have pretty solid connection through optical fiber, this is not hardware problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how it is possible but these problems disappered after I switched to WIFI on my laptop. I have MSI GT70 which has Killer e2200 Atheros gigabit ethernet. It is likely that cause of this problems is driver/software for manage network traffic (Qualcomm bigfoot) which prefer packets of games. I can't tell for sure because I didn't find any other driver for my configuration.